# how to escape url with php inside inline css?

Tags: php, css, escaping

Thanks for looking at this question.

When testing a page with an image called dynamically into the background of a wordpress widget, I get the message "Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page" regarding the image called by this line of code:

```
<div class="row sal-feature-wrap" style="
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
   background-size:100% auto; 
   background-image: url('<?php echo (strpos($image_base_url,'http://') !== 0 ? 'http://'.$image_base_url: $image_base_url); ?>
            ');">
```

I've tried replacing the background-image line with:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url((strpos($image_base_url,'http://') !== 0 ? 'http://'.$image_base_url: $image_base_url)); ?>
            ');">
```

and also with:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url(strpos($image_base_url,'http://') !== 0 ? 'http://'.$image_base_url: $image_base_url); ?>
            ');">
```

Both return the image I want, but the error message remains.

Also, in all cases the apparently identical error message appears twice, I'm not sure why.

How can I properly escape this output?

Thanks

Comment: mixed content error will be fired by the browser when you are on a secured `https` page and the page has some insecure `http` resources, like images, js files , css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid [Mixed content warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content#how_to_fix_your_website) in console. Render your img with `https` protocol:

```php
<div class="row sal-feature-wrap" style="
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
   background-size:100% auto; 
   background-image: url('<?php echo (strpos($image_base_url,'://') === false ? 'https://'.$image_base_url: str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $image_base_url )); ?>
            ');">
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought this solved it at first because it took away the warning message, but then I noticed that the image is not loading and the link to it is resolving to 
`https://http://example.com/etcetera`
How do I correct this?

Comment: I should add that when I echo `$image_base_url` I get `http://example.com/etcetera` and I have no control of that source. I suppose I could strip out the first 8 characters of that string but perhaps there's a more direct solution?

Comment: Do you say images could have `http` protocol and not?

Comment: @amyK can you direct send `'https://'.$image_base_url` ?

Comment: Yes - embarrassing though - how do I direct message on here?

Comment: @amyK I think you can check first if it has a procol finding `'://'`, then add manually  `http;//` if it is false, and otherwise use `str_replace` function to replace protocol

Comment: But images need to be available to be served by https protocol

Comment: in the meantime I tried adding new variable, `$image_base_url_ = substr($image_base_url, 7);` and replaced `$image_base_url` with `$image_base_url_` in your original suggested code. This worked! I just tried your second version, it also worked.